# MKPinAnnotationView and custom classes conforming to the MKAnnotation protocol

Tags: iphone, mkannotation, mkannotationview, mkpinannotationview, mapkit

I have created the following method for determining the view for my annotations in a map view.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) 
{
    return nil;
}

MKPinAnnotationView *pin;

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[AnnotationsWithIndices class]])
{
int i = [(AnnotationsWithIndices *)annotation index];


if (i > currentCheckpointIndex ) 
{

    pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mv dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"unvisited"]; 
    if (!pin) 
    {
        pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"unvisited"];
    }
    [pin setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorRed]; 
}   

if (i == currentCheckpointIndex) 
{
    pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mv dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"current"];
    if (!pin) 
    {
        pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];
    }
    [pin setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorGreen]; 
}

if (i < currentCheckpointIndex) 
{
    pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mv dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"visited"]; 
    if (!pin) 
    {
        pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"visited"];
    }
    [pin setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorPurple];
}
[pin setAnimatesDrop:YES];
return [pin autorelease];
}
else
     return nil;
}
```

The idea is that I want the different annotation views (pins) be of different colors depending on whether the user has visited them to signal which annotation to visit next.

This code works fine, but I have a few questions about it which I hope someone can answer.

Firstly, the MKPinAnnotations are dequeued from a map view and reused whenever possible. In the line doing so (which I have found in multiple blogs and forums)

```
pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mv dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"unvisited"];
```

I understand that the return value of the `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:` is an instance of MKAnnotationView, whereas `pin` is a pointer to an instance of MKPinAnnotationView (which is a subclass o MKAnnotationView). This, I guess, is why there is a 'cast' seemingly going on with the prefix `(MKPinAnnotationView *)` in front of the method call. Is this really a cast and in this case, is it not dangerous since the MKPinAnnotationView contains more instance variables (than MKAnnotationView) and hence more space in memory?

I have tried to find some information about this, but nowhere I have not found anyone explaining this in particular.

Furthermore, the pointer annotation is either of class MKUserLocation or of my own custom class `AnnotationsWithIndices` conforming to the MKAnnotation protocol. Now, in order to determine which color the annotation view should have I have added an instance variable called index into the `AnnotationsWithIndices` class. Now, when I call the getter for the index I write

```
int i = [(AnnotationsWithIndices *)annotation index];
```

Now, I basically have the same question about this. Is there a cast going on here or is it just to let the compiler know that it is ok to send the message index to annotation? I guess that the compiler expects annotation to be an id  whereas it really is a pointer to an instance of AnnotationsWithIndices. 
Of course I know that this is the case since the annotation will be of my custom class, and I also check this explicitly to be sure. Is the `(AnnotationsWithIndices)` there only to signal to the compiler that this is OK?

I have also tried to find information about this without luck.

I am very thankful for any answers on this.